# Split string by regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string by the following array of characters:

```
"!", "%", "$", "@"
```

I thought about using regex, so I developed the following method which I thought would split the string by the characters:

```
var splitted = string.split(/\!|%|\$|@*/);
```

However, when I run the following code, the output is split by every character, not what I was hoping for:

```
var toSplit = "abc%123!def$456@ghi";
var splittedArray = toSplit.split(/\!|%|\$|@*/);
```

How could I make it so that `splittedArray` contains the following elements?

```
"abc", "123", "def", "456", "ghi"
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@*` matches the empty string and there's an empty string between any two characters, so the string is split at every single character. Use `+` instead:

```
/\!|%|\$|@+/
```

Also if you meant the `+` to apply to every character and not just `@` then group them up:

```
/(\!|%|\$|@)+/
```

Or better yet, use a character class. This lets you omit the backslashes since none of these characters are special inside square brackets.

```
/[!%$@]+/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
var splittedArray = toSplit.split(/[!%$@]+/);
```

Your current code will split between every character because `@*` will match empty strings.  I am assuming since you used `@*` that you want to consider consecutive characters a single delimiter, which is why the `+` is at the end of the regex.  This will only match one or more characters, so it will not match empty strings.

The `[...]` syntax is a character class, which is like alternation with the `|` character except that it only works for single characters, so `[!%$@]` will match either `!`, `%`, `$`, or `@`.  Inside of the character class the escaping rules change a little bit, so you can just use `$` instead of `\$`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added explanation, I usually post the code first and then add details in an edit.